# pChart:render the image to browser and embed in html

Tags: html, embed, pchart

I have a class name 'MonthReport.class.php' and  its structure like the following:

```
    class MonthReport{
    .....
    //some member variables


    public function pieChart(){
      ........
      //the image data comes from mysql and data belongs to a specified user
      $myPicture->Stroke();
   }

   public function lineChart(){
      ........
      //the image data comes from mysql and data belongs to a specified user
      $myPicture->Stroke();
  }

   public function render html(){
    $html.=str1<<<
    .....
    //some html code
str1;
   $html.=<<<str2
   <img src="$this->pieChart()" />    //can not work
str2;
  }
}
```

when I call the pieChart() function with this in the place src it will overwrites my entire page and just shows the image.how can I do this?
I try to render the image in a separate page but the image need some specified user data eg.'userId'.in others words when i new a object, it specify the userId,so I can not render the image in a separate page.
sorry for my bad english!but I need your help!thanks in advancd!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear but if your problem is what I am assuming it to be, then I used to have similar issues (Graphic created that is just an image with all of the rest of my page content not displaying). My solution was to generate a temporary image using `pchart` then embed that file in the html

```
 $myfilename = "temp_image.png";      // temp file name
 $myPicture = new pImage(700,500,$myData);  

 // other image creation code....


 $myPicture->Render($myfilename);     // generate image "temp_image.png"
 $image_html = '<img src="' . $myfilename . '">';   //generate the link
 print("$htmlline");
```

Again there is some guesswork going on here as your question is unclear. The above works for me though and enables me to embed an image created on the fly by `pChart` into my `php` pages.

Comment: you are right!render a temp image can solve my problem.but I don't want to store the picture in my web server!I already find a solution that seems foolish!thanks!

Comment: @tudouya OK well if you find a different solution, please post it as an answer here as I would be interested in finding the answer to this myself.